# Aura Flow Component opens the inactive version flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I have deactivated all the versions of a particular flow but still the `lightning:flow` component opens the latest version of the flow. Why it still accessing the latest version?

Comment: Do you have Manage Flow permission?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, Yes user has the Manage Flow Permission

Comment: Thanks for confirming on it. I have checked with Product team and I have answered the same .

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, I got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the product team this behaviour is expected Only with users having "Manage Flow " permission.

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url.htm)

> Only users with the Manage Flow permission can run inactive flows. If the flow contains subflow elements, the referenced flows must also have an active version.